# How to resolve background issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my android flutter application after entering in the text box for typing phone number, the phone text box is not moving to the top. It is hiding by the numbers. So, How to resolve this issue?  Background image  bg.png size is 789X1665 . So, Need to resize the bg image or need to add some code changes? Please help anyone to resolve this issue.

```
  return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,

  body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image : DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.contain
        )
    ),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [

          SizedBox(height: 500,),

          Container(
            margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                "Phone (OTP) Authentication",
                style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20) ,
              ),
            ),
          ),

          SizedBox(height: 10,),

          SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            height: 50,
            child: CountryCodePicker(
              onChanged: (country){
                setState(() {
                  dialCodeDigits = country.dialCode!;
                });
              },
              initialSelection: "IN",
              showCountryOnly: false,
              showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: false,
              favorite: ["+1", "US", "+91", "IND"],
              hideSearch: true,
              showDropDownButton: false,
              enabled: false,
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,right: 10,left: 10),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Phone Number",
                  prefix: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    child: Text(dialCodeDigits!),
                  )
              ),
              maxLength: 12,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: _controller,
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => OTPControllerScreen(
                  phone: _controller.text,
                  codeDigits: dialCodeDigits!,
                )));
              },
              child: Text('Next',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    )
  )

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset=true;` to specify if the body should resize when the keyboard appears.
You can also wrap the parent `Container()` with `SingleChildScrollView()`

Comment: Not understand. Please expLAIN CLEARLY OR EDIT MY CODE

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,`, that should fix your issue and also you shouldn't be doing this `SizedBox(height: 500,),` or `SizedBox( width: 400, height: 50,` Use **padding** instead!

Comment: Can you edit my code?

Comment: Hey just remove resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, from your code, and your issue will be solved!

Comment: Great then, now your phone textbox can move up when clicked on it, also you can mark this answer as the correct answer so people facing a problem like yours can get the right answer!

Comment: After removed facing same issue